# How to retrieve the processed file name, file path and save the result in a csv file using arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

We have a list of feature-classes which are in multiple gdb's in multiple folders. This code is opening the csv and doing "***GetCount_management***" for the listed feature_classes alone and printing the output. The code is printing correctly. Say, if there are 25 feature classes in the csv, it's listing all the counts of all the 25 files. But while saving it in csv, only the 25th count i.e the last file's count alone is getting saved. I don't know whats the issue.

```
import csv
import arcpy
from os import path
csvpath = r"D:\RTXQAQC\Open2.csv"
output = r'D:\Test\Test_2.csv'
csvdir = path.split(csvpath)[0]
with open(csvpath, "r") as csvfile:
    fcs = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(csvfile)]
for fc in fcs:
    result = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
    count = int(result.getOutput(0))
    print(count)
with open(output, 'wb') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    csvwriter.writerow([fc,result])
    f.close()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to define what you mean by "merge", and include your effort at this code within the question.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: If you use a with clause, you don't need to call close() on the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this line:

```
with open(output, 'wb') as csvfile:
```

should be:

```
with open(output, 'wb') as csvwriter:
```

Comment: Getting this error

AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'writerow'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
I hope this will work.

```
import csv
import arcpy
import os
from os import path
csvpath = r"D:\RTXQAQC\Open2.csv"


output = r"D:\Test\testssss.csv"
csvfile=open(output, 'wb')                                          #binary opened
csvwriter=csv.writer(csvfile)

csvdir = path.split(csvpath)[0]
with open(csvpath, "r") as csvfile:
    fcs = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(csvfile)]
for fc in fcs:
    result = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
    count = int(result.getOutput(0))
    print(count)
    csvwriter.writerow(count)
```

Comment: Showing this error "Sequence expected". Actually i've edited the question. If possible, could you have a look

Comment: I just habe a look in your script. I thing you are writing the results outside for loops. you also did not write count , you wrote  results

Answer (score 0):

This is the code. As Shiuli Pervin pointed out in the comment, previously i was writing the results outside the for loop. I think, that's why it didn't get iterated.

```
import csv
import arcpy
from os import path
csvpath = r"D:\RTXQAQC\Open2.csv"
output = r'D:\Test\Test_2.csv'
csvdir = path.split(csvpath)[0]
csvwriter = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
with open(csvpath, "r") as csvfile:
     fcs = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(csvfile)]
     with open(output, 'wb') as f:
         for fc in fcs:
             result = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
             count = int(result.getOutput(0))
             print(count)
             csvwriter = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
             csvwriter.writerow([fc,result])

     f.close()
```